# Require a file for all db:migrate?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not sure the "right" way to do this, so I wanted to ask the community.  Probably a simple question.

I have a file "dbutils.rb" that I want to automatically include to have available whenever I run a "rake db:migrate", without putting it in application.rb and without putting it in every single db migration.

Where would I put my require to make this happen?

Comment: write your custom Rake task that will include your `dbutils.rb` and then pass request to original Rake task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails defines `$rails_rake_task = true` in the `:environment` task.

The `:environment` task again is always loaded when you run `:migrate` (it is loaded for other Rake tasks also). You could use this to add `require "dbutils"` to your environment.rb when `$rails_rake_task` is `true`. And skip loading otherwise.

The other option is a custom Rake task like fl00r suggested.